# Expected initializer before ‘<’ token In Linked List Stack Header File

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

So I have had a problem when I try to compile. The error seems to be in my header file.

```
#ifndef GENERIC_LINKED_LIST_STACK_H_
#define GENERIC_LINKED_LIST_STACK_H_
#include "Node.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <class Type>
class genericLinkedListStack
{
    public:
    genericLinkedListStack();
    int size() const;
    void push(Type element);
    Type pop();
    bool empty() const;
    int top();

    private:
    node <Type> *first;     
};

template <class Type>
int stack<Type>::size() const
{
    node<Type> *newNode;
    newNode = new node<Type>;
    int count = 0;
    while (newNode!= NULL)
    {
        count++;
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
    return count;
}

template <class Type>
void stack<Type>::push(Type element)
{
    node<Type> *newNode;
    newNode = new node<Type>;
    newNode -> data = element;
    newNode -> next = first;
    first = newNode;
}

template <class Type>
Type stack<Type>::pop()
{
    node<Type> *current = first;
    Type element = current -> data;
    delete current;
    return element;
}

template <class Type>
bool stack<Type>::empty() const
{
    return first == NULL;
}

template <class Type>
void stack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()
{
    first = NULL;
}

template <class Type>
void stack<Type>::top()
{
    return front->data;
}


#endif // GENERIC_LINKED_LIST_STACK_H_
```

Every time I compile my files (including the header file), I get this error:

```
expected initializer before ‘<’ token
```

And I get this error on the following lines: 23, 37, 47, 56, 62, 68. 
I have reviewed countless questions online seeking a solution to my answer but it seems as if this problem consists of a more specific problem, there does not really exist a universal solution.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT 1: The Node.h File

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
struct node
{
    Type data;
    node *next;
};

#endif //NODE_H_
```

All the errors I get (in the header file)

```
genericLinkedListStack.h:23:10: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
int stack<Type>::size() const
         ^
genericLinkedListStack.h:37:11: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void stack<Type>::push(Type element)
           ^
genericLinkedListStack.h:47:11: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 Type stack<Type>::pop()
           ^
genericLinkedListStack.h:56:11: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 bool stack<Type>::empty() const
           ^
genericLinkedListStack.h:62:11: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void stack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()
           ^
genericLinkedListStack.h:68:11: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
 void stack<Type>::top()
           ^
```

Comment: Is that the first or only error you get? What is `stack`? Can you reduce this to a [mcve] that includes the definition of `node`?

Comment: Will work on it asap

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to provide the definitions for functions belonging to a class named `stack`, however your class is called `genericLinkedListStack`.

Comment: I had a feeling that was causing my errors. Will work on it immediately.

Comment: So for the lines like this: 
  `void stack<Type>::push(Type element)`
I replaced them with:
    `void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::push(Type element)` 
However, by doing that, I get new errors:

Comment: `genericLinkedListStack.h:62:59: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
 void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()`
                                                           
`genericLinkedListStack.h:68:6: error: prototype for ‘void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::top()’ does not match any in class ‘genericLinkedListStack<Type>’
 void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::top()`
      
`genericLinkedListStack.h:16:7: error: candidate is: int genericLinkedListStack<Type>::top()
   int top();`

Comment: Because in your class definition, you've defined the top function as `int top();` but in the definition for top, you've got it as `void stack<Type>::top()` - the return types are different.

Comment: Oh okay, what should I change in the top function then?

Comment: `void stack<Type>::top()` should be `int stack<Type>::top()`, to match what you put in the class definition.

Comment: Did you find my answers helpful, or do you need more help?

Comment: Yes, your answer did help. Sorry for my late reply, took a small break from coding haha.

Comment: For now, this is the only error I get: 
`error: return type specification for constructor invalid
 void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()`

Comment: Not sure exactly where the problem is there.

Comment: Constructors don't have a return type, not even void. Change `void genericLinkedListStack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()` to be `genericLinkedListStack<Type>::genericLinkedListStack()`. Feel free to accept this as the answer, if you feel it's been useful :)